# how to convert device model uboot driver to use it for older version uboot like uboot 2010

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I am trying to use freescale dspi driver ,but its only available in recent ubooot releases and hence having a device model ,but i want to use it for uboot 2010 ,so how can convert a device model driver to use it.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

Really, it's not feasible to move all of the driver-model infrastructure back to something that old.  You're better off moving your board up to the modern version of U-Boot.

Comment: ok , so where can i get the theory how spi_claim_bus,spi_release_bus,spi_xfer works so that i can write the driver for my device ,cause all spi drivers of uboot-2010 are different except these functions.